# I need a good 3d drawing of ferropericlase

Tags: molecular-structure, molecular-orbital-theory

I'm not a scientist, I'm an artist and I need a good 3d drawing of ferropericlase, where can I find that?

Thank you!
Niki

Comment: try https://www.mindat.org/min-3161.html#autoanchor11

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "3D drawing". Your tags refer to molecular structure and molecular orbital theory. Is it a drawing showing the schematic arrangement of atoms in a crystal of the substances what you are looking for?

Comment: The question is a bit fuzzy, however as you are in NYC, to get in touch with the group around Bart Kahr both interested in crystal growth/structure/properties as well as the visual arts might be fruitful, https://www.kahrlab.com/

Answer (score 2):

Ferropericlase is a solid solution of $\ce{FeO}$ and $\ce{MgO}$ having a rocksalt structure. Your best bet is a rocksalt schematic with the cations randomly labeled $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$.